# Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to create a letter to my clients. I already have an existing template for the letter and some of the contents (client's name/address) will be populated from the database. I have written a code for Classic ASP that opens up the letter template(Microsoft Word) document and populating the client's name/address from the database. However, I received an error message saying that I can't create an object "word.application".

I have tried to debug this problem. Alot of the people in the forum has been suggesting to download Microsoft Word as a workaround for this issue. However, this is not possible because the script has been running fine all this while without having Microsoft Word in the server. Please try to advise me on the possible solutions that I can take to resolve this problem.

```
dim strPathInfo, strPhysicalPath, objFSO, objFile, arrContact, letterType
    letterType = ""
    set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    select case letter_type
        case "iD1"
            letterType = "Acknowlegment Letter"
        case "iD2"
            letterType = "Approval Letter"
        case "iD3"
            letterType = "Approval Letter (Landed Project)"
        case "iD4"
            letterType = "Non-Compliant Letter"
        case "iD5"
            letterType = "Withdrawn Letter"
    end select
    if not letterType = "" then
        set wrd = Server.CreateObject("word.application") //ERROR LINE
        Set newdoc = wrd.Documents.Add 
        newdoc.Range.InsertFile "D:\\Tfcc_Template\\" & letter_type & ".dot"
```

Comment: You can't use Word on your server if you don't have it installed there. But installing Word is not the solution. That application is not made to be used on a server. There are Open XML API's that you can use to create "word" documents server-side. Added bonus is that they are a lot faster

Comment: You must be missing something because to use the Word COM objects they would have to be registered in the Windows Registry, which would happen during setup. The libraries have to be installed from somewhere, so while you think it wasn't installed you are probably wrong with that assumption.